# Android gradle - After update multiple errors showed up

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've spent several days on this and every time I fix an Android's error two new ones came up.

I'm working in a Cordova project and after I update my andrid SDK to API 26 stopped working, gradle always fails.

[image]

SDK Manager
[image]

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

Much appreciate any help

Comment: You must be using these library dependency in your project. The build tool version as well as the dependency version for these library should remain same to avoid any conflict.
Either downgrade these dependency to 26.1.0 or update you build tool version to 27 which is currently seem updated till 26 version only.

Answer (score 0):

**Google's new [Maven repo](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven) is required for the latest support library that is compatible with Android 8.0**

Add this to your Code:

```
repositories {
    google()

    // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
    // maven {
    //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // }
}
```